# How do I get a numerical value of HyperGeometric2F1 function in Mathematica?

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica

I need to plot a function that uses the built-in 2F1 function.  First I want to print out the value of the function in a couple of points.  But the printed value just shows the 2F1 function with arguments, not the actual value of the function.

Here is my Notebook entry:

```
Clear[z1, zEQ, dFS1, dFS2, z]
z1 = 0.4*10^6
zEQ = 3400
dFS1[z_] = (15.6/Sqrt[z])*HyperGeometric2F1[1/2, 1/6, 7/6, -2.33/z^3]*
  UnitStep[z - z1]
Evaluate[dFS1[10^9]]
Evaluate[dFS1[0.4*10^6]]
dFS2[z_] = 
 15.6*{(1/Sqrt[z1])*
     HyperGeometric2F1[1/2, 1/6, 
      7/6, -2.33/z1^3] + ((z + 1)/z1^(3/2))*
     HyperGeometric2F1[1/2, -1/6, 5/6, -2.33/z1^3] - (Sqrt[z + 1]/z1)*
     HyperGeometric2F1[1/2, -1/6, 5/6, -2.33/(z + 1)^3]}*
  UnitStep[z1 - z]
Evaluate[dFS2[0.4*10^6]]
Evaluate[dFS2[0]]
LogLogPlot[{dFS1[z], dFS2[z]}, {z, 10^9, 
  0}, {ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", PlotRange -> Full}]
```

Here are the results of the first two Evaluates:

```
0.000493315 HyperGeometric2F1(1/2,1/6,7/6,-2.33*10^-27) (* for dFS1[10^9] *)
0.0246658 HyperGeometric2F1(1/2,1/6,7/6,-3.64063*10^-17) (* for dFS1[0.4*10^6] *)
```

The reason I want to get the numerical values is that the LogLogPlot does not show any data, it just shows an empty plot (and starts at z = 10^6?).  I would also like any advice how to get the Plot to show my function.

[Plot of dFS function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2W0c.png)

I tried just plain

```
dFS[z1]
```

first, then tried

```
Simplify[dFS[z1]],    
ExpandAll[dFS[z1]],
Evaluate[dFS[z1]],
```

and last

```
Evaluate[dFS[0.4*10^6]].
```

I also tried to wrap the two function definitions with Simplify[,z>=0], thinking that maybe Mathematica thought z is complex.

They all returned the same expression, already shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I predict you are going to kick yourself in a few seconds.

If you read [Hypergeometric2F1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html) really really carefully

then you should see that it is spelled

```
Hypergeometric2F1
```

and not

```
HyperGeometric2F1
```

The help system could do a better job of pointing out little things that need to be corrected.

You might also change `dFS1[z_]=...` to `dFS1[z_]:=...` and `dFS2[z_]=...` to `dFS2[z_]:=...`

but that is a completely different issue

;}